# WebsitePanel 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net

I am going to upload my first site that written in with Visual Studio 2012 and sql 2012 in websitepanel. but I could not understand why this site not upload up fine. I think this problem is because the Web configuration. If it is possible please see this file and help me. Thank you.

```
      <configuration>
      <appSettings>
      <add key="SecurityKey" value="Syed Moshiur Murshed"/>
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>
      <add name="EshopConnectionString" connectionString="user id=*****;           pwd=*****;data source=yourshop.ir_Eshop.mssql.serverpars.com;    persist security info=False;initial catalog=yourshop.ir_Eshop"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
   <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.aspx"     type="Safa.Security.Captcha.SafaCaptchaImageHandle r, SafaCaptchaControl"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
   <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Comment: Disable custom errors (locally). Turn on debugging (in the compilation directive). Read the actual error message.

Comment: tnx for your reply. i set <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>. can u explain more?

Comment: Then the 500 may be from the web.config itself. For one, `type="Safa.Security.Captcha.SafaCaptchaImageHandle r..` is incorrect.